# How to crop object(s) from coordinates(left, top,right,bot) obtained from YOLO?

Tags: python

For example if the output of my Yolo object(s) detection model are the coordinates --
Doll-100%
left=735, top=1983, right=812, bot=2053
How can we crop the object(doll) using those coordinates in OpenCV?

Comment: is that yolo format coordinate? also give some sample image

Comment: Yes it is of some sample image.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Ever image has a different output resolution form some reason(I don't know why). So seeing the width and height of the image I could find out x, y, w and h from left, top, right and bot and could crop the required object.